# Factorial Trailing Zeroes, Error?

Tags: c

```
   #include<math.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
       long i,j[100000],k,l,T,a,n[100000],c,sum=0,m;
       scanf("%ld\n", &T);
       for(c=1; c<=T; c++)
       {
           n[c] = 0;
       }
       for(i=1; i<=T; i++)
       {
           scanf("%ld", &j[i]);
           printf(" \n");
       }
       for(k=1; k<=T ; k++)
       {
           for(l=1; j[k]>pow(5,l); l=l+15);
           a=l++;
           n[k] = j[k];
           while(a>0)
           {
               n[k] = n[k]/pow(5,l);
               sum = sum + n[k];
           }
           n[k] = sum;
       }
       for(m=1; m<=T; m++)
       {
           printf("%ld \n", &n[m]);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   long pow(long x,long y)
   {
       if(y==0)
           return 1;
       else
       return(x*pow(x,y-1));
   }
```

Error :Conflicting types for POW

And is the program correct otherwise?
Here is the program statement
Input

There is a single positive integer T on the first line of input (equal to about 100000). It stands for the number of numbers to follow. Then there are T lines, each containing exactly one positive integer number N, 1 <= N <= 1000000000.

Output

For every number N, output a single line containing the single non-negative integer Z(N).
Example

Sample Input:

```
6
3
60
100
1024
23456
8735373
```

Sample Output:

```
0
14
24
253
5861
2183837
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow` is defined in `math.h` which you also define in your code. The `pow` in `math.h` has signature: `double pow(double x, double y)` which is causing the conflict.

Use either the `math.h` `pow` and remove your version. Or use the one you implemented and remove `math.h`.

If you are using your version of `pow` in `gcc` use `-fno-builtin-pow` to stop detecting the `pow` as builtin, so that your version of `pow` is used.

Comment: Probably the answer is removed. Can you please re-post it ?

Comment: [Defining your own external function `pow`] still invokes UB. You must rename the function or make it static to avoid UB.

Comment: even if compiling with `-fno-builtin-pow` for gcc ?

Comment: Yes. It has nothing to do with builtins. Since `pow` is permanently reserved in the external namespace, **any function** in the standard library could call `pow` as part of its internal operation. If you've replaced it with your own function, this would horribly break. As a stupid example, a really bad `printf` implementation could call `pow` repeatedly for dealing with powers of 10 printing decimal integers...